# Python cotejamiento reporte excel con Pandas

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7, pandas, utf-8

estoy generando un reporte con el módulo Pandas en Python la data la obtengo desde MySQL, pero existe una columna con datos con acento, al momento de generar el reporte se cae, les dejo información relacionada con el problema.

Código de conexión:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(*datosDB)
con.set_character_set('utf8')
```

Donde cargo los datos:

```
multiple_dfs([
    pd.DataFrame({u"Equipos":[]}), title_eq, **#aquí se caee**
    pd.DataFrame({u"Información":[]}),data_eq, 
    pd.DataFrame({"Periodo Seleccionado":[]}),dperiod,
    pd.DataFrame({"Desc":[]}),indic,perc[[" ","dB(A)","db(C)","dB(Z)"]],
    pd.DataFrame({"Segundos":[]}),detalles], "Info", 'tmp/'+equipos+'_'+inicio+'.xls')
```

Error:

```
python2.7[11875]: return self.writer.write(data)
python2.7[11875]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
python2.7[11875]: data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
python2.7[11875]: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solución,

Fue necesario agregar después del

```
import sys

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Con esto fue solucionado el problema.